# '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Node'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement the Huffman coding algorithm but keep getting this error due to the comparisons for the priority queue.
My code:

```python
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def children(self):
        return(self.left, self.right)
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return 0

def create_tree(count):
    print(count)
    priority = queue.PriorityQueue()
    for value in count:
        priority.put(value)
    while priority.qsize() > 1:
        one, two = priority.get(), priority.get()
        node = Node(one, two)
        priority.put((one[0]+two[0], node))
    return priority.get()
```

I've tried multiple attempts of using _*lt*_ in my HuffmanNode class but always end up with can't compare 'str' to 'Node', 'int' or 'tuple'. I'm wondering if it's possible to do this and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit: Also count for create_tree is a list of tuples that looks like:
`[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`

Code that should produce error:

```python
[(1, 113), (1, 107), (1, 98), (1, 120), (1, 106), (1, 118), (1, 108), (1, 122), (1, 121), (1, 100), (1, 87), (1, 70), (1, 10), (2, 84), (2, 117), (2, 99), (2, 119), (2, 102), (2, 109), (2, 97), (2, 46), (3, 110), (3, 112), (4, 114), (4, 115), (4, 116), (4, 103), (5, 104), (5, 101), (7, 105), (8, 111), (18, 32)]
```

Also realized I changed my code so it uses ASCII values rather than strings but I get the same error whether it's 'int' or 'str'

Comment: I can't reproduce any error: `create_tree([(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')])` works fine, as does `n < 1`. Could you provide the code to produce an error?

Comment: Just added it. Actually just realized I changed my code so it doesn't use strings, I can change it back but I don't think it makes a difference either way. I get the same error whether it's 'int' or 'str'

Comment: How should `(2, Node(left=(1, 'a'), right=(1, 'b'))` sort with `(2, 'c')`? `SortedQueue` looks to the data element if the priority elements are the same.

Comment: To get the error you need to remove the `__lt__()` method from `Node`.

Comment: @SuperShoot, that's why I'm wondering if it's possible. Removing __lt__() doesn't fix the error.

Comment: No, removing `__lt__()` creates the error, that's what we want, code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is lifted straight out of the docs for [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue):

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry
>   is the one returned by `sorted(list(entries))[0])`. A typical pattern
>   for entries is a tuple in the form: `(priority_number, data)`.
>
> If the data elements are not comparable, the data can be wrapped in a
>   class that ignores the data item and only compares the priority
>   number.

The example code they give is:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any

@dataclass(order=True)
class PrioritizedItem:
    priority: int
    item: Any=field(compare=False)
```

Using the example that you provided for `count = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`:

```
def create_tree(count):
    print(count)
    priority = queue.PriorityQueue()
    for value in count:
        priority.put(value)
    while priority.qsize() > 1:
        one, two = priority.get(), priority.get()  # one == (1, 'a'); two == (1, 'b')
        node = Node(one, two)  # node == Node(left=(1, 'a'), right=(1, 'b'))
        priority.put((one[0]+two[0], node))  #  (2, Node(left=(1, 'a'), right=(1, 'b'))  <== error here
    return priority.get()
```

When your code adds `(2, Node(left=(1, 'a'), right=(1, 'b'))` to the `PriorityQueue` the other element in the queue, `(2, 'c')` has the same priority, so the data element is used to sort.

So, you need to either explicitly ignore sorting by data (see the docs example above for some guidance), or define how `'c'` should sort relative to `Node(left=(1, 'a'), right=(1, 'b'))` and implement it. For example if you always want `Node` to sort last relative to some other data type:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return True

def __gt__(self, other):
    return False
```

Or vice versa:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return False

def __gt__(self, other):
    return True
```

Or something more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

When you implement `__lt__()`, you create the comparison for `Node < int`, but not `int < Node`.

To get this, we need to reverse the operation:

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection.
>
> [Python data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

In other words, when evaluating `B < A` i.e. `B.__lt__(A)` and `B` does not define a suitable `__lt__()` method, it uses `A.__gt__(B)` instead.

To fix this, add the following to your `Node` class:

```
def __gt__(self,other):
    return 0 # or something else intelligent
```